# the Nullity of N is equal to the number of summands in the cyclic decomposition of V

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove the following? Let V be a finite-dimensional vector space and N be a nilpotent linear operator on V.Then the Nullity of N is equal to the number of summands in the cyclic decomposition of V.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Each cycle of generalized eigenvector contains one eigenvector, and each eigenvector is an element of the nullspace of $N$.